# Django - Save multiple object with form.save()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In my application there must be two inputs which will get numbers, and when I'll click`create` button in the given range (which was written in inputs) difference of that number times object must be created. For example, in first input I'll write "2", in second "5", 3 objects must be created. Here are my codes:

`models.py`:

```
class Blank(models.Model):
    blank_series = models.CharField(_('Blankın seriyası'), max_length=3)
    number_from = models.IntegerField()
    number_to = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.blank_series
```

`forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Blank

class CreateBlankForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blank
        fields = '__all__'
```

`html`:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ form.blank_series.label }}</td>
  <td>{{ form.blank_series }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{{ form.blank_number.label }}</td>
  <td>
    {{ form.number_from }}
    {{ form.number_to }}
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="create-blank-btns">
    <button class="create-blank-btn"><span class="material-icons">add_circle_outline</span><input type="submit" value="Əlavə et" name="create-blank"></button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

`views.py`:

```
@login_required(login_url='sign-in')
def blanks(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlankForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CreateBlankForm()

    blanks = Blank.objects.all()
    
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'blanks': blanks,
    }
    return render(request, 'blank.html', context)
```

Comment: what object you want to create multiple times?

Comment: You want to create `Blank` object multiple times ?

Comment: @arjun, yes, but in each loop blank's series must be changed. Number between begininng and end of range must be assigned to series

Comment: What is blank series?what will be changed in blank series ?

Comment: @arjun, OH MY GOD, man ! look at the codes please, if you want to help.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in two ways 1)override save method in model form 2)get cleaned data in the view and save multiple times

1)override save method in model form in the model form

```
class CreateBlankForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blank
        fields = '__all__'
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        times = self.number_to - self.number_from
        for i in times:   
            super(CreateBlankForm).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

2)get the cleaned data on the view get the cleaned data and loop over in save method

```
@login_required(login_url='sign-in')
def blanks(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlankForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            times = form.cleanded_data['number_to'] - form.cleaned_data['number_from']
            for i in times:
                form.save()
    else:
        form = CreateBlankForm()
    blanks = Blank.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'blanks': blanks,
    }
    return render(request, 'blank.html', context)
```