# Django how to iterate a form and save multiple objects?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a modelform (model: `Student`) with a `TextField` where the user enters several names at once.  My intention is for my view to parse this text input (getting a first name, last name, and then coming up with a nickname) and loop through the lines, saving a new student each time through the loop.  However, only the last time through the loop is a student saved.

In the past I have solved this problem by using a custom save method in my model but I wanted to try doing it all in the view. I saw some posts in stackoverflow [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053312/django-save-multiple-object-with-form-save) where it seemed that others were able to iterate through a loop and save objects.

```
models.py
class Student(models.Model):
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_first = models.CharField(default='John', max_length=30)
    student_last = models.CharField(default='Smith', max_length=30)
    nickname = models.CharField(default='JohnS', max_length=31)
    attend = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    do_not_pick = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    multistudentinput = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname

forms.py
class MultiStudentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('multistudentinput',)

views.py
def addmultistudent(request, classroom_id):
    classblock = Classroom.objects.get(id=classroom_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MultiStudentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            student = form.save(commit=False)
            # save the classroom that the student belongs to
            student.classroom = classblock
            student_list = []
            student_list = student.multistudentinput.split('\n')

            for line in student_list:
                line = line.strip('\r')
                all_names = line.split()
                num_names = len(all_names)
                if num_names == 2:
                    last = all_names[1]
                    student.student_last = last
                else:
                    last = ' '
                    student.student_last = ''
                student.nickname = all_names[0] + last[:1]
                student.student_first = all_names[0]
                print(student)
                student.save()

            form = MultiStudentForm(None)
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, "gradebook/addmultistudent.html", context)

        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, "gradebook/addmultistudent.html", context)

    else:
        form = MultiStudentForm(None)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "gradebook/addmultistudent.html", context)
```

Comment: You shouldn't put `multistudentinput` in `Student` model. Also `MultiStudentForm` should be a custom form instead of a ModelForm, so user can input multiple users and then in the view you iterate and create `Student` object for each one. Also, it's best to use `bulk_create` for this operation. It's more efficient. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: @PooyaKamranjam I read about bulk_create but I wasn't sure about the repercussions of save() not being called. I will try this out as well.